# C++ child class using parent class function

Tags: c++

I got a bit of issue here.

- Vehicle is parent class
- Car and Motorcycle is child class

this is my main cpp file

```
int main() {
    // assuming max size is up to 100
    VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];
    int vehicleCounter = 0;

    Car *car = new Car();
    Motorcycle *motor = new Motorcycle();

    cout << " Please enter name of vehicle ";
    cin >> vehicleName;

    if (vehicleName == "Car") {
        vehicletwod[vehicleCounter] = car;

        //issue here
        vehicletwod[vehicleCounter].setName(vehicleName);
        //issue end

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my car.cpp

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

class Car: public Vehicle {
private:
    Point wPoint[4];
    double area;
    double perimter;
public:
    void setType(string);
    void setPoint();
    string getType();
    string getPoint();
}
```

The issue here is setName is a function of Vehicle, but not a function of Car. but i did the inheritance which should inherit the function. but doesn't seems to work.

It say...Request for setName in vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]' which is of non class type VehicleTwoD*

**Above Issue is fixed**

Additional Issue:

Okay i fixed the previous issue by changing . to ->

Here the other issue.

as the code is. on this part

```
 if (vehicleName == "Car") {
            vehicletwod[vehicleCounter] = car;

            vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]->setName(vehicleName);


           //now i want to setPoint which is a function of child class
           vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]->setPoint();
           //issue here
        }
```

I try  to setPoint which is a function of child class, Car

However it say.. Vehicle has no member named 'setPoint'

**After doing what John mention.. the above issue is also fixed..**

But the hardest part is on how to retrieve what been set since it is a vehicletwod object and not a car object.

Assume after setPoint, i want to getPoint()

i try do this

vehicletwod[0]->getPoint();

I get an error saying getPoint is of non-class type 'vehicletwod'

Comment: What is VehicleTwoD? Does Car inherit from VehicleTwoD?

Comment: OK the issue really seems to be what `VehicleTwoD` is, which despite at least three requests now you are still not telling us.

Comment: OK see my edited answer below.

Comment: I did but the additional issue not there :)

Comment: after did the adding, how do i retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK still don't know what `VehicleTwoD` is but you would be closer to correct if you wrote

```
vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]->setName(vehicleName);
```

instead of

```
vehicletwod[vehicleCounter].setName(vehicleName);
```

You have an array of pointers, so you need to use `->`.

The other problem is that `setPoint` is only a member of `Car`, `not Vehicle`, so you have to call it on your car **before** you add it to your array.

Something like this

```
if (vehicleName == "Car") {
    car->setPoint();
    vehicletwod[vehicleCounter] = car;
    vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]->setName(vehicleName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats fixed the issue, can you look on the additional issue on top.

Comment: Thats fixed again :) you r the best.

Comment: But now the question is , since i add everything to assume vehicletwod[0] , how do i cout my point that i set, assuming i got a function call getPoint() which return Point struct

Comment: I can't call getPoint because it wont work as it say it is of non-class type of vehicletwod

Comment: @user1777711 Well this is a problem. Forget about C++ for a minute. You have an array of all sorts of Vehicles, Cars, MotorCycles etc. etc., but only the Cars have a Point. What do you expect to happen if you try to get the Point from a Vehicle that is not a Car? Until you answer that question it's not possible to say what the right thing to do in C++ is. Another way of saying this is, what's the point of adding a Car to a Vehicle array, if after you've done that we want to treat it as a Car again? These are *design* questions not programming questions.

Comment: @user1777711 The only way to answer design questions is if you explain what you are trying to do. What the big picture here? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate Car and Motorcycle differently:

```
VehicleTwoD *car = new Car();
VehicleTwoD *motor = new Motorcycle();
```

then declare the methods you want to use in child classes as protected.

You are welcome!

PD: A car is not VehicleTwoD, taxonomy matters.

Answer (score 0):

vehicletwod[vehicleCounter] is a pointer so you need to dereference it. Try vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]->setName(vehicleName).

You might want to read up on pointers. Google "c++ class pointer basics" or checkout http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Pointers

Answer (score 0):

It seems lik `VehicleTwoD` doesn't have a method like this:

```
protected:
virtual void setPoint();
```

You need this because of the definition of the array.

Answer (score 0):

VehicleTwoD has not setPoint(), so you must dynamic_cast VehicleTwoD * to Car*, but you must make sure vehicletwod[vehicleCounter] really points to an object of Car, otherwise it's a runtime error!

```
dynamic_cast<Car*>(vehicletwod[vehicleCounter])->setPoint();
```

The best way  is make setPoint() as a pure virtual function of VehicleTwoD;

```
class VehicleTwoD {
public:
    virtual void setPoint() = 0;
    /***/
};
```

implement the setPoint() in derived class.